# Closures - Difference between capturing variables and reading them as arguments

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, closures, anonymous-function

Let's say we have this class:

```
// Provides deferred behaviour
public class Command<TResult>
{
     private Func<object[], TResult> _executeFunction;
     private object[] _args;

     public Command(Func<object[], TResult> execution, params object[] arguments)
     {
          _executeFunction = execution;
          _args = arguments;
     }

     public TResult Execute()
     {
          return _executeFunction(_args);
     }
}
```

What's the difference between these two anonymous functions?

```
int a = 1;
int b = 4;

// a and b are passed in as arguments to the function
Command<int> sum = new Command<int>(args => (int)args[0] + (int)args[1], a, b);

// a and b are captured by the function
Command<int> sum2 = new Command<int>(_ => a + b);

Console.WriteLine(sum.Execute()); //Prints out 5
Console.WriteLine(sum2.Execute()); //Prints out 5
```

I'm specifically looking for performance differences.

Also, we know that if some class is holding a reference of `sum2`, then `a` and `b` will live beyond the scope they were defined on, probably never getting collected by the GC if the function is still referenced anywhere.

Does the same happen with `sum`? (Considering the arguments are reference types and not value types as in this example)

Answer (score 1):

When you pass in the variables `a` and `b`, you are doing just that.  The value of `1` and `4` are passed in respectively.  However, when you refer to `a` and `b` within the context (or scope) of the lambda expression the values are "captured".  The variables `a` and `b`, within the scope of the lambda expression are treated as references to the originals outside of the scope, meaning that if they are changed within the scope of the lambda -- so too are the originals.  When compiled into IL, they reside in a class where the instances are shared.

```
static void Main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 4;

    // a and b are passed in as arguments to the function
    var sum = new Command<int>(args => (int)args[0] + (int)args[1], a, b);

    // a and b are captured by the function
    var sum2 = new Command<int>(_ =>
    {
        var c = a + b;

        a++;
        b++;

        return c;
    });

    Console.WriteLine(sum.Execute()); //Prints out 5
    Console.WriteLine(sum2.Execute()); //Prints out 5

    Console.WriteLine("a = " + a); // Prints 2
    Console.WriteLine("b = " + b); // Prints 5

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

There is really small difference in the IL, and I do not believe there is any performance implications worth avoiding one or the other.  I would usually prefer the usage of lambda expressions for their readability.

[A look at some of the IL generated from some C# lambdas](https://sparethought.wordpress.com/2012/08/17/implicit-closures-in-c-lambdas/).